# How to escape backtick in docker-compose.yml file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run PHP built in web server as startup for my container, but docker-compose up complain that it failed to parse the ` symbol (backquote? backtick?) in my docker-compose.yml

Here's my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  sf-api:
    image: reston/php:7.1
    ports: 
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ".:/tmp/target"
    working_dir: "/tmp/target"
    command: ["php","-S","`hostname -i`:8000"]
```

What I'm trying to do is to make the web server binds to container external IP instead of 127.0.0.1.

Edit:
Here's the output running docker-compose up

```
$ docker-compose up
Recreating storefrontapi_sf-api_1 ...
Recreating storefrontapi_sf-api_1 ... done
Attaching to storefrontapi_sf-api_1
sf-api_1  | Invalid address: `hostname -i`
storefrontapi_sf-api_1 exited with code 1
```

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message

Comment: Docker compose didn't parse the backtick, the log and error is from your app. Where do you expect the command to be run, on your host or inside your container?

Comment: @BMitch i intend to run the command inside container. If compose feeds the entire command as is, the backtick suppose to be parsed as subcommand by the shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You explicitly told docker-compose to not run your command inside a shell with the json exec syntax for your command. If you want the shell the parse the backticks inside the container, you'll need to run your command with a shell. Note that this will break things like signal handling since the shell in pid 1 will intercept and ignore a SIGTERM (it assumes it's in single user mode where you don't want the shell to exit). The string syntax for a command runs a shell for you, or you can change your command to explicitly launch a shell. Either of these should work:

```
command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "php -S `hostname -i`:8000"]   
command: "php -S `hostname -i`:8000"
```

Comment: Upvoted this on the basis that the first line solves my specific problem. There's the posibility the (default) shell inside the container is not bash, so it cannot parses backtick properly. the image I'm using was based on alpine.

Comment: @bluearth The default shell from docker is always /bin/sh unless the image explicitly overrides it, which would be a mistake with an Alpine image. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell

Answer (score 0):

I did ended up the first time with the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  sf-api:
    image: reston/php:7.1
    ports: 
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ".:/tmp/target"
    working_dir: "/tmp/target"
    command: ["php","-S","0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

I bind to *any available interface*. It worked on my situation since there were only two interface: loopback and eth0. Might not be the case for everyone.

Yes, It's present me stumbling on the same problem over again and ended up here. Again. Leaving answer here for future me and others.